# Access-Control-Allow-Origin suddently doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, tomcat

We have a mobile app which only runs on ipad. In the app, user submits a form and the app will use js/jquery to call a restful service on server. The server is a tomcat 6 and web application uses spring + hibernate frameworks. at the dev server we have encountered the cors problem and i added the corresponding filter in web.xml INSIDE my app and of course the jar files. It went well on the dev, qa and live server and the app could communicate with the server in harmony. But later today i just got a error report from the client that the app can't upload the data to server unless reinstall the app, in which way all the data saved in app would be gone. I tested using either javascipt and also inside the app. The weird thing is I always got the exception using the script:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mobilesso.vw.com.cn/ssso/scc/registerSCCF. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

and always am able to upload the data to server via app. I was wondering why it is happening right now. The mobile app and the web appliation works togother fine for like a week and why it stops from now on. And why there is no issue inside the app but js does. Any advice would be helpful.

There is the client test code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="address-candidate-template">
var request = null;

function getMessage()
{
    alert("Begin the test");
    createRequest();
    var url = "my url";
    request.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function createRequest() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (trymicrosoft) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("MsXML2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (othermicrosoft) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }

    if (request == null)
        alert("Error creating request object!");
}

function handleResponse() {
    alert(request.readyState + " " + request.status);
    if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
    {
        var xmlDocument=request.responseXML;
        var fnames = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("statusCode");
        var v1 = fnames[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        fnames = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("statusText");
        var v2 = fnames[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        alert("Result:\nstatusCode: " + v1 + "\nstatusText: " + v2);  
    }

}
</script>
<div>
    <p>test the connectivity</p><input type="button" value="Get Result"   onclick="getMessage()"/>
```

And i used following maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And set the WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
 <!-- CORS Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin suddenly doesn't work"  Well, I can assure you that the world's web browsers suddenly change how they use this header on your site.  How are we supposed to know why this stopped working?  You didn't show any code that was changed, nor did you show us the HTTP request/response.  Only you know this information.

Comment: I have no access of the client code. I have written some test code on my own which used to be successful but not anymore. Please see the update

Comment: Will be great if you will add some network logs with request and response headers. You can get them in chrome/firefox developer tools for example (easiest way). At least that is the first step you should start from - check the actual headers.